# adding archive to application using firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an application for elderly people where they can add there medication and  i store them in firebase they can delete medication but I don't want that medication  to be deleted  forever I want to save all medications into history page even if the medication  was deleted it will be saved in the history or you can say archive so any suggestion what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a field that is exactly the same as the field that stores data Create an interface and link it to the new field and before deleting from the user field, put the data in the new field in addition to a new field Store the date and time of deletion

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

- The set-up in each medicine **`enum`** contains several cases.
- **`enum`** contains several states:

  1- `Deleted`

  2- `Archives`

  3- `Effective`

  ... etc

When the user deletes a specific medicine, you can **change** the status of the medicine to `“Deleted”`.

In this case, when retrieving the data, you can check the returned **`enum`** accordingly, and you can view, hide, or archive this medicine.

I hope this method may help you.